# How can I login with my bash terminals running in interactive mode?

Tags: bash, login, ldap

I am using a domain controller (oldap) to authenticate my hosts. It all works great except for the fact that my ldap users are initializing with **non-interactive** shells.

I know the issue is not with the user per-se as the skeleton home directory is being copied successfully and I can successfully emulate an **interactive** shell by executing `bash -l`.

Does anybody know where I can configure the user's loading process? or the shell/tty/terminal loading process?

I know there has to be some config file that will determine that the default shell should be called with the interactive option, but I can't find it.

PS: another strange side-effect is the element order of my PATH variable. Usually, the first path items are `/usr/local/{sbin,bin}`, then the `/user` *bins*. I'm not sure that this relevant though

Answer (score 3):

I found it in my case! Quite easy, in fact! For starters, run

```
ldapsearch -xLLLH ldap://<dc_uri> -b <dirbase> uid=<username> '*' > user.ldif
grep loginshell user.ldif
```

In my case, the user had a wrong login shell assigned (`/bin/sh`) which for me means **dash** and not **bash**.

Solution is simple. Transform the *user.ldif* description file into a modifier and then run `ldapmodify` with enough credentials.

```
# ldif
dn: uid=<username>,<dirbase>
changeType: modify
replace: loginShell
loginShell: /bin/bash
```

Then run

```
ldapmodify -xWH ldap://<dc_uri> -D <adminuser> -f modUser.ldif
```

If you're scared this might blow up in your face, run with `-nv` options, so you can get a verbose simulation of what's going to happen